# Android Gallery Image onTouch to fit screen

Tags: android, image, touch-event, window-managers

I am developing application having a resemblance appearance  like " Gallery application".
When I click on image from the gallery... I want  to fit image to whole screen..
I used this code..but it does not work .
can you guide me for this ...
Here is code for the same:

```
  Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
  int width = display.getWidth();
  int height = display.getHeight();

  imgView.setMinimumWidth(width);
  imgView.setMinimumHeight(height);

  imgView.setMaxWidth(width);
  imgView.setMaxHeight(height);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use the following attribute of the imageview to fit the image to the screen.

Controls how the image should be resized or moved to match the size of this ImageView.

Must be one of the following constant values.

Constant    Value

matrix            0

fitXY             1

fitStart      2

fitCenter     3

fitEnd            4

center        5

centerCrop    6

centerInside      7

`android:scaleType="fitxy"`

like wise you can use others to change the size of your image.

Comment: you need to tell him *which* attribute (**cough** `scaleType` **cough**)

Comment: `android:scaleType="fitxy"`
like wise you can use others to change the size of your image.

Comment: I'm just saying your **answer** doesn't mention `scaleType` at all. You should edit it so he knows. :) He also seems to be trying it programmatically. You might include the code variant too, but that's not necessary for your answer to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider having the image open in its own activity, with android:noHistory="true" in the manifest, and onClick() have it end the activity. That way you don't have to worry about the image resizing and ruining everything in the activity it is being chosen in.